# Using C# as a scripting language for a C# application

Tags: c#, scripting

I have developed an application that uses c# script files for certain configurations and settings. The script file contains various user generated objects and certain functions on those objects. Presently, the user has to generate a .cs file using a third party editor and supply the path to my program to make use of it. The disadvantage with this method is that the user does not have the flexibility of Auto-complete and intellisense-esque support while editing the script files.

I want to embed the script editing part into my application. I can do that using a rich-text editor. But coding the auto-complete part is a huge pain. Is there any way in which I can provide the user with an in-program editor that also does auto-complete....

Code for compiling a script dynamically in a program.

```
public String Compile(String inputfilepath)
    {

        CompilerResults res = null;
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        String errors = "";

        if (provider != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Assembly asb = Assembly.Load("BHEL.PUMPSDAS.Datatypes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=81d3de1e03a5907d"); 
                CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();
                options.GenerateExecutable = false;
                options.OutputAssembly = String.Format(outFileDir + oName);
                options.GenerateInMemory = false;
                options.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
                options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
                options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
                options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
                options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
                options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(asb.Location);
                res = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(options, inputfilepath);
                errors = "";
                if (res.Errors.HasErrors)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < res.Errors.Count; i++)
                    {
                        errors += "\n " + i + ". " + res.Errors[i].ErrorText;
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw (new Exception("Compilation Failed with Exception!\n" + e.Message +
                    "\n Compilation errors : \n" + errors + "\n"));
            }

        }
        return errors;
    }
```

Comment: Lua, Python or powerscript? Which script language are you using?

Comment: C# itself is my scripting language. I am using the CodeDom namespace to compile C# script files on the fly from within my program.

Comment: oh my god! C# is your script? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes !! It's pretty simple to use too...

Comment: Laugh, :) C# is generally not regarded as a scripting language. Google it, believe me!

Comment: @David, please familiarize yourself with [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx).  In particular:  "and the upcoming support for scripting and interactive use of VB and C#."

Comment: +1 for the Link. Reading...

Comment: @david Updated the question with sample code. The overlords at Microsoft have spoken !!

Comment: @KirkWoll you should make that comment into an answer. It is the answer I was going to provide. "Use roslyn".

Comment: @JoshSmeaton I have gone through the link. How does Roslyn provide me the ability to fireup / embed a text editor that does autocomplete for objects written in the user script?? Do you know of any examples??

Comment: @RaghavendraKumar I haven't used Roslyn so I'm not going to be much help at all I'm afraid. But it is a compiler as a service. To do auto-complete and syntax highlighting etc you need to analyse the code. Roslyn provides tools to do proper C# analysis. Otherwise you'll need to build, from scratch, a mini-compiler. That's not something you want to do if you can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for auto-complete, you will need to make use of two systems: a parser, and reflection.

A parser is a pretty straightforward concept, in theory, but I'm sure that it won't be easy to write for a language with as much syntactic sugar and as many context-sensitive keywords as C#.

Since .NET is inherently reflective, and provides a reflection framework, that part shouldn't be incredibly painful, either.  Reflection allows you to manipulate the object-oriented elements comprising compiled assemblies--and the assemblies themselves--as objects.  A method would be a `Method` object, for example.  You can take a peek at this system by examining the members of the `Type` class, which provide one basic starting point for reflection.  Another useful starting point is `Assembly`.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx), as usual, has a wealth of "official" information in a structured format.

Comment: Your method works on systems which are already compiled. What I want is Visual studio style Intellisense, which works even before the code is compiled.

Comment: Which essentially means you're compiling it as you go.  Same idea.  You can still use reflection; the framework is in place.  You're basically compiling an object-oriented shell.  You'll need to do something custom for local variables, but that's just one element.